# Recommended Configuration to setup Tomcat 7 on windows OS

Tags: mysql, tomcat, configuration

I have created a small web application using java/jee which will be deployed in LAN environment. I want to know the recommended hardware configuration.

Details are as follows

1) Expected number of hits: 20 hits / hour
2) Number of clients 5-7

3) Application Server : Tomcat 7
4) Database server : MySql

*App and DB shall be deployed on same machine*

5) OS Configuration : Windows XP or any unix flavour ?

Can a simple p4/celeron machine with 1 gb ram 8-10 GB hard disk will be sufficient to cater client requests? Server will not be storing too many files/images/videos

Client does not want to spend too much on infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say go with windows since, to my understanding, you have more flexibility with installation type. (although, cost-wise you want to look into unix). With windows you can install Tomcat as a service that can be set to auto-startup or you can install Tomcat over a java location. Just remember that the Tomcat administration web app can only be accessed when Tomcat is running. ;)